# Can I add main function in C++ header file?

Tags: c++

Hi guys I have a vehicule.h header file like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vehicule{
    private:
    string type;
    //etc...
};
//can this function be there or do i need to add it on .cpp file?
int main(){
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can, but this results in very limited possible use of the header. The language itself doesn't differentiate between header files and `.cpp` files. That is just convention, which doing this does however break. Why do you want to do this or think that it is necessary/advantageous?

Comment: Do not use `using namespace std` on a header though.  Some would go even further to say never write that at all.

Comment: Having your definition of `main` in a header file seems likely to lead to a [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) violation, assuming that `vehicule.h` is `#include`d into more than one cpp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically yes, you can. However, if you do put a non-inline function definition such as `main` into a header, then you may only include the header into one translation unit. This makes the header rather pointless. In conclusion, don't do it because it isn't useful.

Comment: I think it is useful in my case because when I write unit tests, each test suite is an executable and I use a common header file with main() to avoid writing it for each test suite. Not sure if it's a good practice though.